# How to log in a user using Spring security manually?

Tags: java, spring

I created a user with a fake username and a password. I tried to log in this user with java code. I can obtain username correctly by

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()
```

However, the jsp tag

```html
<sec:authorize access="!isAuthenticated()">
```

is still false. And `<sec:authentication property="name" />` is anonymousUser. How can I fix it? Thanks

```
Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new GrantedAuthority() {
            //anonymous inner type
            public String getAuthority() {
                return "ROLE_USER";
            }
        }; 
        grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);

        User tempUser = new User(username, passwd, true, true, true, true,  grantedAuthorities);

        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(tempUser, "", grantedAuthorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
        User authUser = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        session.setAttribute("username", authUser.getUsername());
        session.setAttribute("authorities", authentication.getAuthorities());
```

Comment: From what class is your code snippet? Is it in a filter declared before or after the default Auth filter?

Comment: Nope, in fact, I connect my website to other website such as Facebook, user log in Facebook and I receive user information from Facebook. Then I try to regard this user as those who had logged in my website and I try to  show his facebook name on my website with tag <sec:authentication property="name" />. I just want to give this user Authentication